# How to prevent page to go to bottom using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When the user clicks on the button, new content gets loaded from the javascript.  However, the page automatically goes to the bottom.  How do I get the page to stay in place so the user can scroll to the bottom and then click on the button (after they have seen the new content loaded)?

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      counter = {{page}};
      counter = counter-1;
       $("#load_more_videos").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log(counter);
        $('.more_videos').load("/more_videos/"+counter);

       })
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method='get' action = '' id = 'load_more_videos'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value='Get more videos'/>
    </form>

<div class = 'more_videos'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) inside the load event callback like:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$('.more_videos').load("/more_videos/"+counter, function () {
    $('html body').scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

**NOTE:** `This is completely untest and might make the page a little jumpy`

Comment: What if I don't want to go to the top?  The user can click on this multiple times and each time it should go to the top of the new section loaded.